# Mysql self join with multiple order by

Tags: mysql, join

assume we have table

id, title, date

I need to build 1 query to:

```
select date = TODAY, order by id
select data < TODAY, order by date desc,
select data > TODAY, order by date asc,
```

Comment: Can't you just write the 3 requests and combine them in one query with the **UNION** keyword ?

Comment: Hmm, is order or "sub parts" preserved after UNION ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus -- I believe so, see fiddle for simplified example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ef06/2

Comment: @sgeddes well, thx, seems like it works, the danger is that UNION will take distinct values from all "sub parts". If you don't get distinct data, you've got a problem  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ef06/12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `UNION` and sub queries:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Date(dateField) = Date(Now())
    ORDER BY ID 
) t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE dateField < Now()
    ORDER BY dateField DESC
) t2
UNION
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Date(dateField) > Now()
    ORDER BY dateField 
) t3
```

Here is a simplified [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ef06/2) example.

Good luck.

Comment: Just hard to scrap nearly the exact same query. Even chose the same re-name of the dateField.

Comment: And, please, how to Limit this query?

Comment: Yes, limit 10 results for whole query

Comment: Literally add " LIMIT 10" to the end of the above query... See this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ef06/4 Good luck :)

Comment: And how to count results with count(*)?